# Update the apphostconfig file using appcmd

Tags: iis, azure-devops, appcmd

In an azure devops pipeline I try to run an appcmd command to modify the applicationhost.config file to set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable
It works fine like this:
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /+"[name='api.hostname.net'].environmentVariables.[name='ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT',value='api.hostname.net']"

The problem is that this appcmd command works the first time, but as soon as the environment variable already exist it will throw an error message. Can I somehow ignore errors from appcmd? Or only add the environment variable if it does not exist from before?

I'm running appcmd commands using an azure devops IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0 task.

Comment: Always delete it first and then create it. Then you can run the sequence multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `XML transformation` option in the IIS web deploy task. XML transformation supports transforming the configuration files (*.config files) and is based on the environment to which the web package will be deployed.

[image]

Transform file sample:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <aspNetCore ...>
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="xxx" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement, and I have to scriptize these commands, so any UI-based method doesn't work for me. Provide my solution here.

I want to update an existed key named `PasswordChangeEnabled` which is located in `appSettings` section.

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="PasswordChangeEnabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

If I use `set config` with plus `/+`

```
appcmd set config "Site" /section:appSettings /+"[key='PasswordChangeEnabled',value='true']"
```

I will get an error message:

> ERROR (Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique
> key attribute 'key' set to 'PasswordChangeEnabled')

So I changed the syntax to just modify the value:

```
appcmd set config "Site" /section:appSettings /"[key='PasswordChangeEnabled'].value:true"
```

This way worked for me.